# package--check-signature-content error when running package-list-packages in Emacs 27

Tags: gpg, list-packages, emacs27

I recently upgraded to a GNU Emacs pretest 27 (version 27.0.91) running on MS Windows 10 platform.

With `package-check-signature` defaulting to `allow-unsigned`, I modified `init.el` so Emacs can work with signature keys using directory `~/.gnupg`, where I have additional keys stored/managed through `gpg2`, installed under Cygwin setup.

This lets Emacs startup import `gnu-elpa.gpg-keyring` correctly, but when listing/upgrading Emacs packages I still see the following error related to signature verification:

```
error in process filter: package--check-signature-content: Failed to verify signature: file-error, "Writing to process", "Bad file descriptor", #<process epg>
error in process filter: Failed to verify signature: file-error, "Writing to process", "Bad file descriptor", #<process epg>
```

which requires either `package-check-signature` set to `nil` to be silenced before proceeding to upgrade packages. If I re-run list packages command, returned error message is:

```
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done

error in process filter: package--check-signature-content: Failed to verify signature: file-error, "Writing to process", "Invalid argument", #<process epg>
error in process filter: Failed to verify signature: file-error, "Writing to process", "Invalid argument", #<process epg>
```

Tried looking online, but couldn't find anything meaningful related to my issue.

Comment: You should report this as a possible bug using the [Reporting bugs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bugs.html#Bugs) process.

Comment: (You are running a pretest, not a released Emacs version. Bugs are likely.)

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. Happy to contribute in Emacs v27 testing :). In terms of reporting possible bugs, how do I figure out where the error could lie - in Emacs or a package related to gpg?